# Yocto Build Fail Using BB_NO_NETWORK=1

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I know that there are a few similar posts out there, but I don't see anything for my specific issue.

Yes, I'm using an ancient yocto release: sumo. I can't change that at this time because this is product code, and yes, I know that sumo is going EOL and won't get security updates. Another battle for another time.

The error is the dreaded:

```
Network access disabled through BB_NO_NETWORK (or set indirectly due to use of 
BB_FETCH_PREMIRRORONLY) but access requested with command 
<some git command which must access the network>
```

Here is the root cause of the problem, as far as I can tell:

**In code.qt.io, Qt has removed branch 5.12.11 and replaced it with branch 5.12 and tag v5.12.11**

This is fixable using the method I outline below, but there are some cases in which such a fix does not work.

Initial fix is to change meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qt5-git.inc to refer to the tag, which should be within the branch:

```
QT_MODULE_BRANCH ?= "5.12"
QT_MODULE_BRANCH_PARAM ?= "branch=${QT_MODULE_BRANCH}"
QT_MODULE_TAG_PARAM ?= "tag=${SRCREV}"

# each module needs to define valid SRCREV
SRC_URI = " \
    ${QT_GIT}/${QT_MODULE}.git;name=${QT_MODULE};${QT_MODULE_TAG_PARAM};${QT_MODULE_BRANCH_PARAM};protocol=${QT_GIT_PROTOCOL} \
"
```

Also, in some qt repos, the tag commit is no longer the same as the original branch commit, so I'm patching that up in the individual `meta-qt5/**/<qt_module>_git.bb` file for the moment. I will eventually create .bbappend files for these changes.

This works for most qt5 recipes, but I'm getting hung up in qtbase-native. Seems that the tag, v5.12.11 has a commit which is not in the 5.12 branch. In fact the commit doesn't seem to be in any branch. I copied a command from the fetcher log, modified it slightly, but it returns nothing, which is where things go off the rails:

```
~/dev/manifest-mbio-dfh-full-lockdown/build/ \
downloads/git2/code.qt.io.qt.qtbase.git$ git branch \
--contains c1ff120f34797b2d705b7a8a371cad443bba6a1d --list 5.12
```

The fetcher expects to see output from this command, namely the line which has the name of the branch.

Is there some way I can cajole yocto into fetching a specific commit which is not associated with any branch and without going to the network?

**EDIT:** I did try to leave out the branch spec altogether, but the fetcher simply defaults to master. This doesn't help because I don't think there is a master branch. At least I didn't see it in a git branch listing. I also tried setting the tag param to specify `"ref=${SRCREV}"`, but that resulted in the same issue with the branch being set to master by default.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer is to set the `QT_MODULE_BRANCH_PARAM` to `"nobranch=1"` and set the `QT_MODULE_TAG_PARAM` to `ref=${SRCREV}`. This forces the fetcher to ignore the branch spec.